# Flex regular expression for comments

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to learn flex and having trouble with a regular expression to catch comments.

Assuming a comment begins with `//` and runs to the end of the line, I would like the program to recognize the entire comment and set `yytext` equal to it.

So far `["//".*$]` is not cutting the mustard.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your text in square brackets creates a character class matching any one character from among those between the brackets.  Also, quotation marks are not special in Flex's regex syntax.  You want something along these lines:

```
/* definitions (for more readable rules) */

/* The \134 are octal escapes for the '/' character, for clarity: */
CMNT_START \134\134

%%

/* rules */

{CMNT_START}.*$  /* yytext automatically contains the matched text*/;
```